# Looking for videos/GIFs of petrification/permineralization

Tags: geology, minerals, fossils

Do you know of any good animations, videos, or GIFs of petrification/permineralization? For some students verbal and written explanations don’t work, they don't always visualize well. So it’d be better to visually show minerals coming in & taking the place of organic molecules.
It would be great to see a representation of a fossil, and the zoom to a close up of a bone... then zoom in to show molecules. (They don't even have to be atomically correct. Just colorful and distinct.) Then show molecules of some other shape/color come in, and slowly displace the previous ones.